# How to show each 5 categories in 1 chart, in SSRS Reports (visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio, charts, reporting-services, crm, power-platform

I am working on SSRS reports (visual studio)
I have 2 fields: branches, and categories
I have in my chart:
value: count of the categories
in category group: branches and categories
but my problem is that I have 40 branches, and I need to show each 5 branches in 1 chart.
any Solution?

Working on SSRS visual studio reports

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to provide more details, edit your question and explain clearly what you are trying to do. Samples of data and expected outcome are always useful. Please read the following article to help you write your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask